# pytest parallel over multiple docker containers

Tags: python, docker, pytest, pytest-django

I was exploring some options for parallel testing with `pytest`. I first looked into both `pytest-xdist` and `pytest-parallel`, and they would allow me to parallelize my tests inside a single container.

But is it actually possible to parallelize it across multiple containers?